# How to adjust the composition of the site?

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why my `<hr>` takes the whole page horizontally the first two times I use it, then the third one stops a little from the left margin. After the third `<hr>` the whole page sitto of this moves from the margin as much as the `<hr>`
at the bottom I also have the footer that moves as much as the `<hr>`.
could you help me figure out where to change the code?

```css
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #000000;
    padding-right: 0!important;
}

.container {
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}


img {
    max-width: 90%;
}


ul, li{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0;
}


/*USE CSS for Slider*/

.cssSlider {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 45%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.cssSlider .slides {
    overflow: hidden;
  //overflow: hidden;
    width: 45%;
    height: 70vmin;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.cssSlider .slides > li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70vmin;
    position: absolute;
    //z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 45px;
}
.cssSlider .slides > li > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 45px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
/*
.cssSlider .slides > li:first-child:not(:target) {
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
            transform: translateY(0%);
}
*/
.cssSlider .thumbnails {
    //display: block;
    //position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 70px;
    list-style: none;
}
.cssSlider .thumbnails > li {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
  }
//.cssSlider .thumbnails > li > a {
    //display: block;}

.cssSlider .thumbnails > li > a > img {
    margin: 55px;
  width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.cssSlider .slides li:target {
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-animation: slide 0s 1;
}
.cssSlider .slides li:not(:target) {
    -webkit-animation: hidden 1s 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
                transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
                transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
                transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
                transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hidden {
    0% {
        z-index: 3;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
                transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 3;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                transform: translateX(100%);
    }
}
@keyframes hidden {
    0% {
        z-index: 3;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
                transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 3;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                transform: translateX(100%);
    }
}






/* Buttons */
.btn-group1 button {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #c1cfdc;
  color: black; 
  padding: 8px 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: #415971;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white 65%, #f4f6fb 50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-right: 140px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 9px;
}


.btn-group2 button {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #c1cfdc;
  color: black; 
  padding: 8px 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: #415971;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white 65%, #f4f6fb 50%);
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 9px;
}

.btn-group3 button {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #c1cfdc;
  color: black; 
  padding: 8px 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: #415971;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white 65%, #f4f6fb 50%);
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 9px;
}

.btn-group:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none;
}

.btn-group1 button:hover {
  background-color: #f4f6fb;
  background-image: none;
}

.btn-group2 button:hover {
  background-color: #f4f6fb;
  background-image: none;
}

.btn-group3 button:hover {
  background-color: #f4f6fb;
  background-image: none;
}

/* Property */

.Property1{
font-family: Arial;
color: #20381f;
margin-left: 90px;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.Property2{
font-family: Arial;
color: #20381f;
margin-left: 90px;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.Property3{
font-family: Arial;
color: #20381f;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/* informazioni */
.informazioni{
margin-left: 30px;
display: flex;
gap: 110px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.informazioni1{
margin-left: 30px;
display: flex;
gap: 120px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
}

.informazioni2{
margin-left: -310px;
display: flex;
gap: 125px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
margin-top: 25px;
font-family: Georgia;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: lighter;
}

/* simboli cerchi */
.circleshapes{
    display: flex;
    gap:2px;
    margin-left: -540px;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

.circleshapes1{
margin-left: 5px;
}

.circleshapes2{
margin-left: 105px
}

.circleshapes3{
margin-left: 105px
}

/* Icon property */
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 5px;
  gap: 50px;
}

.Icon{
    color: #20381f;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 70px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3%;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.Icon1{
    color: #20381f;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 70px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 3%;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.Icon2{
    color: #20381f;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 70px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 3%;
    margin-top: 0px;
}


/* icone fiori */
.containerinformaizonifiori{
display: flex;
gap: 80px;
margin-bottom:-60px;
margin-left: 5px;
}

.flowerIcon{
    color: #20381f;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.flowerIcon1{
    color: #20381f;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 50px;
}


/* icone colori */
.dot1 {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  background-color: #790c7a;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.dot2 {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  background-color: #faf275;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.dot3 {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  background-color: #f69d40;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.dot4 {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
  background-color: #efa3d0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/BigBang.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/css/BigBang.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e8f8804c71.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title>Big Bang</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- topnav======================================== -->

 <div class="topnav">
 <div style="position:relative;padding-top:0%; bottom: 0;">
    <iframe src="TopNav.html" width="100%" height="55" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    <style>iframe {border: none}</style>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Buttons======================================== -->
<div class="btn-group1"><button>Deluxe<br><br> 42.00€<br><br><br> 30 steli</button></div>
<div class="btn-group2"><button>Premium<br><br>39.00€ <br><br><br>25 steli</button></div>
<div class="btn-group3"><button>Standard<br><br>33.00€ <br><br><br>20 steli</button></div>

<!-- Gallery======================================== -->
<div class="cssSlider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li id="slide1"><img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        <li id="slide2"><img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        <li id="slide3"><img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        <li id="slide4"><img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        <li id="slide5"><img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang5.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li><a href="#slide1"><img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang1.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide2"><img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang2.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide3"><img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang3.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide4"><img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang4.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide5"><img src="/Users/giuliettamotolese/Desktop/Accademia/III ANNO/II Semestre/Web Design/flowerbee/codice/immagini/Big Bang/BigBang5.jpg" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--?auto=format&fit=crop&w=140&q=60-->




<div class="Property1">
<h3>Property</h3>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="Icon"><i class="fa-3x fa-regular fa-clock"></i> </div>
  <div class="Icon1"><i class="fa-3x fa-solid fa-droplet"></i></div>
  <div class="Icon2"><i class="fa-3x fa-solid fa-temperature-half"></i></div>
</div>
  <div class="informazioni"><h4>Durabilità</h4><h4>Fragranza</h4><h4>Resistenza</h4>
   
   
   <div class="circleshapes">
    <div class="circleshapes1">
      <span style='font-size:23px;'>&#9679;</span><span style='font-size:23px;'>&#9679;</span><span style='font-size:23px;'>&#9679;</span><span style='font-size:23px;'>&#9679;</span><span style='font-size:23px;'>&#9675;</span>  
    </div>  
    
    <div class="circleshapes2">
      <span style='font-size:23px;'>&#9679;</span><span style='font-size:23px;'>&#9679;</span><span style='font-size:23px;'>&#9679;</span><span style='font-size:23px;'>&#9679;</span><span style='font-size:23px;'>&#9675;</span>  
    </div>
    
    <div class="circleshapes3">
      <span style='font-size:23px;'>&#9679;</span><span style='font-size:23px;'>&#9679;</span><span style='font-size:23px;'>&#9679;</span><span style='font-size:23px;'>&#9679;</span><span style='font-size:23px;'>&#9675;</span>  
    </div>
    
  </div>
  </div>  
  </div>



<hr style="margin-top: 30px;  width: 100%;">




<div class="Property2">
<h3>Composition of bouquet</h3>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="flowerIcon">✿</div>
  <div class="flowerIcon1">✿</div>
</div>
    
<div class="containerinformaizonifiori">   
   <div class="informazioni1"><h4>Tulipano</h4><h4>Tulipano</h4></div>
   <div class="informazioni2"><h4>Antartica</h4><h4>Jumbo</h4></div>
</div>

<hr style="margin-top: 30px;  width: 100%;">

<div class="Property3">
<h3>Predominant colors</h3>
</div>
  <span class="dot1"></span>
  <span class="dot2"></span>
  <span class="dot3"></span>
  <span class="dot4"></span>


<hr style="margin-top: 30px;  width: 100%;">

<div class="Property3">
<h3>Description</h3>
<p>An explosion of color and joy: Big Bang. This bouquet includes tulips that enjoy a life of their own, don't you believe it? Each type of tulip moves at its own pace as it grows, changing color, shape and posture. In addition, its fuchsia, orange and yellow are a marvel to behold.</p>
</div>



<!-- footer======================================== -->
<div class="footer">  
  <div style="position:relative;padding-top:0%; bottom: 0%;">
    <iframe src="Footer.html" width="100%" height="370" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    <style>iframe {border: none}</style>
  </div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third `<hr>` is inside the `div class="Property2"` which has css `margin-left: 90px;`

```
<!-- open div, which has margin left -->
<div class="Property2">
<h3>Composition of bouquet</h3>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="flowerIcon">✿</div>
  <div class="flowerIcon1">✿</div>
</div>
    
<div class="containerinformaizonifiori">   
   <div class="informazioni1"><h4>Tulipano</h4><h4>Tulipano</h4></div>
   <div class="informazioni2"><h4>Antartica</h4><h4>Jumbo</h4></div>
</div>

<!-- Do you mean to close </div> here? -->
<hr style="margin-top: 30px;  width: 100%;">
```

Depending on exactly what you want you could close the `div` before the `<hr>` or change the css